# How do I map a list of objects including their Collection member to another object with a Set as member using stream lambdas?

Tags: java, stream, mapping

A List of:

```
Class1
  String string1
  String string2
  List<Class3> list1
```

Mapped to a list of multiple:

```
Class2 
  String copyOfString1
  String copyOfString2
  Set<class4> copyOfList1
```

Edit:
Class 3 contains string members that I want to copy to Class 4 String members.

Comment: is there anything you've tried already?

Comment: You don't need to _copy_ strings. They are immutable.

Comment: How is a `List<Class3>` supposed to become a `Set<Class4>` ? What is the relationship between classes 3 and 4?

Comment: @khelwood Class 3 contain String members that I need to copy to String members of Class 4. I was wondering if this is possible to do with a Stream lambda.

Comment: @itwasntme I know I could write a mapper object, my question was because I was wondering if this is even possible with a Stream lambda.

Comment: @DemCore there's always a need to  write a small mapper, I can show you the example with lambdas if it's still needed

Comment: @itwasntme Yes please I would be very gratefull, I will mark your reply as answered if you could post it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here is where do yo want to convert the **List** to **Set**,
the conversion can be done before **Class3** mapped to **Class4** and after that.

So the struggle here is if you want to make **Set** from **List** and then convert it to **Set** or first apply conversion from **Class3** to **Class4**. This is important because List can contain duplicated values, where the Set contains only of unique values. Making `List<Class3>` to `Set<Class3>` as first operation will depend on the equality of Class3 objects. Making `List<Class4>` to `Set<Class4>` will check the equality implemented for Class4.

The little mapper between objects is always required, if you don't want to explicitly declare mapping method use a copy constructor `Class4(Class3) {...}` for example.

Here's an example:

```
import lombok.*;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.function.Function;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class MappingWithLambdas {
    private static Function<Class1,Class2> c1To2WithMapping = c1 -> {
        Function<Class3,Class4> c3to4 = c3 -> {
            Class4 c4 = new Class4();
            c4.setX(c3.getX());
            c4.setY(c3.getY());
            return c4;
        };
        Function<List<Class3>, Set<Class4>> listToSet = l -> l.stream().map(c3to4).collect(Collectors.toSet());
        Class2 c2 = new Class2();
        c2.setX(c1.getX());
        c2.setY(c1.getY());
        c2.setDatas(listToSet.apply(c1.getDatas()));
        return c2;
    };
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Class1 c1 = new Class1();
        c1.setX("X"); c1.setY("Y");
        c1.setDatas(List.of(new Class3("x", "y"), new Class3("x", "y"), new Class3("x", "y")));
        System.out.println(c1);
        System.out.println("Using mapping function: ");
        System.out.println(c1To2WithMapping.apply(c1));
        Function<Class1,Class2> c1to2WithNew = Class2::new;
        System.out.println("Using Class2 constructor: ");
        System.out.println(c1to2WithNew.apply(c1));
        System.out.println("Simply with constructor: ");
        System.out.println(new Class2(c1));
    }
}
@Data
class Class1 {
    private String x;
    private String y;
    private List<Class3> datas;
}
@Data
class Class2 {
    private String x;
    private String y;
    private Set<Class4> datas;
    private Function<List<Class3>, Set<Class4>> listToSetWithNew = l -> l.stream().map(Class4::new).collect(Collectors.toSet());
    Class2() {}
    Class2(Class1 c) {
        this.x = c.getX();
        this.y = c.getY();
        this.datas = listToSetWithNew.apply(c.getDatas());
//List<Class3>->List<Class4>->Set<Class4>
//        this.datas = c.getDatas().stream().map(Class4::new).collect(Collectors.toSet());
//List<Class3>->Set<Class3>->Set<Class4>
//        this.datas = new HashSet<>(c.getDatas()).stream().map(Class4::new).collect(Collectors.toSet());
    }
}
@Data
class Class3 {
    private String x;
    private String y;
    Class3(String x, String y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
}
@Data
class Class4 {
    private String x;
    private String y;
    Class4() {}
    Class4(Class3 c) {
        this.x = c.getX();
        this.y = c.getY();
    }
}
```

`@Data` annotation comes from Lombok library, which created the setters, getters and toString for me.

And the output of this should look similar to this:

```
Class1(x=X, y=Y, datas=[Class3(x=x, y=y), Class3(x=x, y=y), Class3(x=x, y=y)])
Class2(x=X, y=Y, datas=[Class4(x=x, y=y)])
```

Edit:
You still could to something like this:

```
Class2 c22 = List.of(c1).stream().map(i1 -> {
        Class2 i2 = new Class2();
        i2.setX(i1.getX());
        i2.setY(i1.getY());
        i2.setDatas(i1.getDatas().stream().map(c3 -> {
            Class4 c4 = new Class4();
            c4.setX(c3.getX());
            c4.setY(c3.getY());
            return c4;
        }).collect(Collectors.toSet()));
        return i2;
}).collect(Collectors.toList()).get(0);
System.out.println(c22);
```

But creating List of a single object just to achieve such syntax costs in performance.

Edit2:

I flew away a bit, making the mapper between `Class1` and `Class2` and what you are looking for is probably something like that:

```
Function<List<Class3>, Set<Class4>> convertClassesAndToSet = l -> l.stream().map(c3 -> {
        Class4 c4 = new Class4();
        c4.setX(c3.getX());
        c4.setY(c3.getY());
        return c4;
    }).collect(Collectors.toSet());
Function<List<Class3>, Set<Class4>> toSetAndConvertClasses = l -> new HashSet<>(l).stream().map(c3 -> {
        Class4 c4 = new Class4();
        c4.setX(c3.getX());
        c4.setY(c3.getY());
        return c4;
}).collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

Or something more related to the variable names you've used:

```
Set<Class4> list3ToList4ThenSet = list1.stream().map(c3 -> {
    Class4 c4 = new Class4();
    c4.setX(c3.getX());
    c4.setY(c3.getY());
    return c4;
}).collect(Collectors.toSet());
Set<Class4> list3ToSetThen4 = new HashSet<Class3>(list1).stream().map(c3 -> {
    Class4 c4 = new Class4();
    c4.setX(c3.getX());
    c4.setY(c3.getY());
    return c4;
}).collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

Edit3(or4...):
Samples with the list of Class1 to Class2 objects

```
List<Class2> list2WithConstructor = list1.stream().map(Class2::new).collect(Collectors.toList());
//change this.datas=... in Class2 constructor to:
this.datas = c.getDatas().stream().map(Class4::new).collect(Collectors.toSet());
//or to (depending of your use case):
this.datas = new HashSet<Class3>(c.getDatas()).stream().map(Class4::new).collect(Collectors.toSet());
//then you will feel the real constructor magic ;P
```

And a sample with mapper inside lambdas:

```
List<Class2> list2WithMapper = list1.stream().map(l1 -> {
    Class2 c2 = new Class2();
    c2.setX(l1.getX());
    c2.setY(l1.getY());
    c2.setDatas(l1.getDatas().stream().map(c3 -> {
        Class4 c4 = new Class4();
        c4.setX(c3.getX());
        c4.setY(c3.getY());
        return c4;
    }).collect(Collectors.toSet()));
    return c2;
}).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Ok, it's 1AM here and I'm drunk, good night.

Comment: @DemCore, I've added a additional sample :) but it's very similar to previous ones.

Comment: @DemCore, your question isn't a lot of "-" bad, the "-" are from misleading conversion between `List` and `Set` and the way you want to convert `Class3` to `Class4` and what should go first: listConversionThenToSet or ListToSetThenConversion. The thing in asking SO questions is in accurate statement of the problem, while understanding the underlying concepts.
I would be thankfull if you also could 'upvote' my answer, cause it explains the concepts and the ways of different cases could be achieved.  What time is it out there?

Comment: thank you for your answer, it was like in the middle night, I fell asleep :).I tried upvoting your answer but it said: "Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score."